# UITableView reloadData not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, reloaddata

this is my UITableView code

in viewDidLoad

```
self.audioHistoryTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.audioHistoryTableView.delegate = self;
self.audioHistoryTableView.dataSource = self;
```

table view

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
    NSLog(@"tableeeeeeee %lu",(unsigned long)[audioHistory count]);
    return [audioHistory count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"historyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.audioHistoryTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *audio = [audioHistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = audio;

    return cell;
}
```

when I add data and call reload

```
NSArray *newItem = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"new audio!"];
NSLog(@"new item : %@",newItem);

[audioHistory addObjectsFromArray:newItem];
[self.audioHistoryTableView reloadData];
```

I know it's not work because I add new data and change to other page, when back to this page the added data was shown.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Could you please add the entire method to your question where you update the data and call the reload? Is this method in audioHistoryTableView's view controller or in the other view controller?

Comment: What do your log messages say after you call `reloadData`?  Are they printing?  Are they printing the right things?

Comment: @lightice11 yes, used storyboard

Comment: @LyndseyScott It's in the other view controller. I just add UITableView, not UITableViewController

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, it's print the right things.

Comment: @PhatsaweePuttarukkul like I said, could you please add that entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set the delegate and datasource via the interface builder instead? Also if it's made in the interface builder why do you have to initialise the table? Remove this:

```
self.audioHistoryTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.audioHistoryTableView.delegate = self;
self.audioHistoryTableView.dataSource = self;
```

then in the interface builder control drag from the UITableView up to the UIViewController and set the delegate to self. And do that again and set the data source to self. Try that

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah just try and keep it consistent, if your building in the interface builder then set the datasource and delegate in the interface builder. :)

Comment: @PhatsaweePuttarukkul Yeah, the fact that you reinitialized the table you'd created in the storyboard was the problem. As for setting the datasource and delegate, you can in fact do that programmatically as you've done or in the interface builder...shouldn't matter.